# Can I set a folder pointer location in a class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pointers, directory

I wanted to know if I can set a folder pointer location in a class or some place which can be easily be handled. Can I easily set the location of the images or the content that I am storing in this folder to be managed through these classes, instead of altering the code one by one?

For example, if I move to a cloud tomorrow, I just need to change the pointer in the class and not the entire code of 10 pages and the other way around.

Or in simple words: I am planing to store a bunch of images in C# in folders, but I don't want to hardcode the location of these folders. I was wondering if i can store the location in a specific class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put some config information like this in your web.config file. Here is part of mine:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>
  <location inheritInChildApplications="false">
      <appSettings>
          <add key="domain" value="http://localhost:4059"/>
          <add key="GridRows" value="50"/>
      </appSettings>
```

Then you can get at these properties like this:

```
String websiteDomain = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["domain"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup

1. constants
2. configuration handlers ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx))

I usually prefer to embed resources as... embedded resources ([MSDN HowTo](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292))

PS. Though not necessarily a good choice, you could even do loosely what you say "I was wondering if i can store the location in a specific class": create a class in a separate assembly, use that assembly as a poor-man's-configuration file, simply replacing it with a custom compiled assembly. What this really is doing is akin to 'plugin' loading - this time, the plugin tells you where (and possibly, how) to find the program's resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the location in the configuration file - the `app.config` or `web.config` file.

Use the `ConfigurationManager` class to read from it.

Answer (score 0):

Proceed with `web.config` or in use a database `table` to store the settings. Create a form to add/edit the folder value.
I think, it is not a good idea to store it in class. If you want to change it, you have to compile the code.